# Bucle WHILE para crear archivos PDF (FPDF PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, while, fpdf

Tengo una pagina vinculada a una base de datos Mysql. Realizo una consulta y depende los resultados que arroje son las veces que se ejecuta, aqui va el codigo:

```
$productos_venta_query= $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM productos_venta WHERE id_venta='".$resultado['id']."'") or die($conexion->error);
        
while ($productos_venta= mysqli_fetch_array($productos_venta_query)){
    $producto_query = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id='".$productos_venta['id_producto']."'")or die($conexion->error);
    $producto= mysqli_fetch_array($producto_query);
            
    $date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Buenos_Aires'));
    $fecha = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sA');

    $nombre= $producto['nombre'];
    $imagen= $producto['imagen'];
            
    include '../fpdf/crear_pdf.php';
}
```

el archivo incluido a lo ultimo es el que crea y almacena mis archivos PDF, aqui va:

```
<?php

require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');
$nombrePDF = $nombre.'.pdf';


$pdf = new FPDF('L', 'mm', array(210,110));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image("../images/".$imagen,5,5,200);
//$pdf->Image("../images/1627320160.png",5,5,200);
$pdf->Image('../images/copyright.png',0,0,220);
$pdf->Output("F","../fpdf/pdf/".$nombrePDF);
```

Ahora bien, el error que me da es el siguiente... si el bucle while se ejecuta solo 1 vez, el código anda perfecto, me crea y me almacena el archivo PDF, pero luego, si el bucle while se ejecuta mas de 1 vez, por ejemplo 2 veces, solamente se crea el PDF con el nombre del primer resultado y me arroja el siguiente error en pantalla

```
Warning: Constant FPDF_VERSION already defined in /storage/ssd5/429/17353429/public_html/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 10

Fatal error: Cannot declare class FPDF, because the name is already in use in /storage/ssd5/429/17353429/public_html/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 12
```

Yo necesito en este caso, cuando el bucle while se ejecuta 2 veces o mas, crear la cantidad de archivos PDF igual a la cantidad de veces que se ejecuta el while, cada cual con su respectivo nombre... Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Intenta con el require_once('../fpdf/fpdf.php'); en tu archivo que crea el PDF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para crear multiples PDF utilizando un ciclo necesitas crear una funcion que te permita crear el pdf automaticamente con un diseño establecido, para eso vamos a crear una funcion que nos regresara un PDF, vamos a crearlo utilizando una clase llamada `automate_pdf`

El siguiente codigo tiene que ir en tu `crear_pdf.php` de la siguiente manera

```
<?php

require '../fpdf/fpdf.php';
class automate_pdf extends FPDF{
    
    function generate($name, $img=""){
        if(isset($name)){
            $nombrePDF = $name.'.pdf';
            $this->AddPage();
            $this->Image("../images/".$img,5,5,200);
            //$this->Image("../images/1627320160.png",5,5,200);
            $this->Image('../images/copyright.png',0,0,220);
            $this->Output("../fpdf/pdf/".$nombrePDF,"F");
            
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Una vez creada la clase que hereda (`extends`) las funciones de de nuestra clase `PDF` vamos a modificar el script donde ejecutas tu ciclo de la siguiente manera

```
include '../fpdf/crear_pdf.php';
$productos_venta_query= $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM productos_venta WHERE id_venta='".$resultado['id']."'") or die($conexion->error);
        
while ($productos_venta= mysqli_fetch_array($productos_venta_query)){
    $pdf = new automate_pdf('L', 'mm', array(210,110));
    $producto_query = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id='".$productos_venta['id_producto']."'")or die($conexion->error);
    $producto= mysqli_fetch_array($producto_query);
            
    $date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Buenos_Aires'));
    $fecha = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sA');

    $nombre= $producto['nombre'];
    $imagen= $producto['imagen'];
    $pdf->generate($nombre,$imagen);
            
    
}
```